# Determining the most possible number of winners in a raffle

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Every year we do a raffle at my job with prizes that were donated by local businesses.  Everyone can select 5 prizes they'd like to win from a total of x number of prizes.  After that a winner is randomly selected for each prize and then the people who didn't win what they wanted will get a consolation prize from the pool of prizes nobody won.

I'm doing this all via PHP.  I create an array that looks something like this:

```
$prizeArray[prizeID][$employeesWhoWantThisprizeArray[employeeIDs]]]
```

So for each key prize in the array, the value is an array of employees who want the prize.  This can be anywhere from 0 to n employees.  Then I just foreach through each prize, randomize the inner employee array, and pick a winner.  The winner is added to an array of winners to be checked against so they only win one thing.

I should also point out that before going through each prize, I check to see if there are any prizes with only one employee attached.  If there are, I automatically make that employee win that prize.

In the past, I just re-ran this script until I got the smallest number of losers I could.  But I was wondering if there was a more efficient way than brute force to find this minimum loser count.  Is there an existing mathematical equation or function that solves this kind of problem?  I don't know much about math, so I'm not sure how to even google it.  I'm not even sure what to tag this post with.  Probability?  Statistics, maybe?  Arrays are kinda matrix-like, so I guess I'll throw that in there too.

Thanks!

Comment: Re-running a random simulation until you llike the outcome is not really that much of (fair) random any more. - You might want to directly assign those prizes with only one applicant and perform the random decisions afterward, but then I'd be rather pissed that I cannot compete for that Ferrari any more merely because I also happened to be the only one to also check the cucumber sandwhich on the list.

Comment: Funny you mention that.  As the script stands now, if only one person picked a prize, they win that first.  Since that helps minimize losers, I should probably add that to the main question.  I will do so now.

Comment: Are there as many prizes as people? Or more, or fewer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the maximum possible number of winners, this is a maximum matching problem in a bipartite graph. The left nodes are people, the right nodes are prizes, and there is an edge between person and prize if that person selected that prize.